# MySQL get running difference for unique titles with date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data in MySQL table. Its primary key is domain name and tstamp (date). This table is updated just once a week. Now I want to get a difference of one domain in consecutive weeks on UrduCount column.

Following is the table sample data (for just three weeks but will grow in future)

```
mysql> select * from domainStats order by domain_name limit 10;
+-----------------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
| domain_name           | TotalLinks | Succeed | NotSucceed | NotFetched | UrduCount | tstamp     | src  |
+-----------------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
| 107.170.52.240        |      59574 |   30226 |       1688 |      27660 |     60000 | 2019-10-04 | use2 |
| 107.170.52.240        |      59027 |   30315 |       1689 |      27023 |     40000 | 2019-09-27 | use2 |
| 107.170.52.240        |      59027 |   30315 |       1689 |      27023 |     10000 | 2019-09-20 | use2 |
| www.dunyapakistan.com |      66542 |   20608 |       4844 |      41090 |     30000 | 2019-10-04 | use2 |
| www.dunyapakistan.com |      66542 |   20608 |       4844 |      41090 |     30000 | 2019-09-27 | use2 |
| www.dunyapakistan.com |      65380 |   20192 |       5293 |      39895 |     20000 | 2019-09-20 | use2 |
| www.urdupoint.com     |     129751 |   20746 |        494 |     108511 |     50000 | 2019-10-04 | use2 |
| www.urdupoint.com     |     129751 |   20746 |        494 |     108511 |     50000 | 2019-09-27 | use2 |
| www.urdupoint.com     |     126879 |   20779 |        455 |     105645 |     10000 | 2019-09-20 | use2 |
+-----------------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------+
```

Expected out similar to following (consecutive difference of same domains in consecutive weeks)

```
www.urdupoint.com   | 2019-10-04 | 20000
www.urdupoint.com   | 2019-09-27 | 30000
www.urdupoint.com   | 2019-09-20 | 10000
...
```

Comment: Why is the differnce 10000, 30000 and 20000? Shouldn;t it be 10000, 40000 and 0?

Comment: You could remove unrelated columns from the sample table data. And have a result that matches the whole sample data. (If you want other domains than urdupoint returned.)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.x you can use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT domain_name, tstamp, UrduCount - COALESCE((
    SELECT UrduCount
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.domain_name = t.domain_name
    AND x.tstamp < t.tstamp
    ORDER BY x.tstamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
), 0) AS diff
FROM t
```

In MySQL 8 or later you could simply use the `LAG` function.